# MySQL - How can i query a multi-value field to match a primary key of another table?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. One table contains all of the states in the USA.  The other table is just a list of stuff in those states.

My table is structure looks something like this:

```
tbl_states - stateID (PK), stateName
tbl_stuff - stuffID, stuffName, relState
```

The values look like this

```
1 | Alabama
2 | Georgia
3 | Maryland
```

The relState column relates to the tbl_states.stateID column and i have it in this format. I plan to have a webform to select multiple states and assign the stuff in the states to the state.

```
1 | This is some stuff | 1,2 [ and this stuff is only AL, GA. ]
```

So I'm trying to figure out the best way to write the select statement for this. Is there some way to do it strictly with mysql?

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, does the relState column contain values such as "| 1,2 [ and this stuff is only AL, GA. ]"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-valued fields in a database are a bad idea. Instead, resolve the many-to-many relationship between states and stuff like this:

[image]

Comment: Off topic: what do you use to create your database diagrams so fast?

Comment: @BD - relState would contain a value like 1,2,3,5,10.

Comment: @Joe - sorry working off of really little sleep at the moment.  You are making a table to handle the relationship between the two and add ing a foreign key?

Comment: @Robbiegod: The new `State_Stuff_xref` table would actually have 2 foreign keys, each one relating one of the IDs back to its parent table.

Comment: I actually havent done this too much so what benefit do you get by having the State_Stuff_xref?  I know i must be missing something here.  Can I just query State_Stuff_xref to get information like stateName because the relationship is already made?

Comment: @Robbiegod: You have a many-to-many relationship between states and stuff. That is, each state can have 0, 1 or more "stuff" assigned and each "stuff" can be associated with 0, 1 or more states. What I've given you here is the standard way to normalize that relationship in a database schema.

Comment: ok i think i got it now. I was a little confused if when i make a query if i was supposed to query all 3 tables.  I know now that i am supposed to query all 3 tables. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post while searching to do this myself and figured a second answer would be helpful.  While it is true that multi-valued fields decrease search efficiency, impact scailability and promote data integrity problems, they can be necessary for simplicity, reporting, and integrating with other systems, as in my case it was.

Assuming the Tables:

```
Table: States
Id          Name
235325235   'Alabama'
457457432   'Georgia'
334634636   'Maryland'



Table: Stuff
Id  Text                            StateIds
1   'Some stuff'                    '235325235'
2   'Some Stuff for two states'     '235325235,457457432'
```

The following query would return all stuffs for alabama

```
SELECT * FROM Stuff WHERE FIND_IN_SET('235325235', Stuff.StateIds);
```

Please note that i complicated your ID's more to make a lower probability of uniqueness and I would recommend using a GUID/UUID since you are using a string searching function.